# what is the usage of @ sign before $_SESSION

Tags: php

In a php page I found the below code:

```
<form class="form-inline mr-auto" method="post">

    <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Search Proposals" name="search_query" value="<?php echo @$_SESSION["search_query"]; ?>">

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="search" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>

    </div>

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){

    $search_query = $_POST['search_query'];

    $_SESSION['search_query']=$search_query;

    header("location: $site_url/search.php");

}

?>
```

if you notice then inside the form for input type text there is a php code for value attribute where a session has been called.

```
 value="<?php echo @$_SESSION["search_query"]; ?>">
```

But what is the at sing **@** used for before $_SESSION["search_query"] ? is there any special meaning of at sign?

Comment: @$_SESSION['search_query']; using single coat

Comment: `@` stops errors from being displayed when they occured.

Answer (score -1):

The `@` sign suppresses errors in PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php